# ZXing.Net.Mobile Sample.WindowsUniversal Sample Not Scanning

Tags: win-universal-app, zxing, barcode-scanner

Testing this to incorporate into Win 10 UWP app to scan 1D barcodes (format 39 & 128).  I have updated latest through nuget 2.0.4.46.  Referenced post at http://www.yortondotnet.com/2015/07/mobile-barcode-scanning-with-zxingnet.html regarding some options setting prior to scan() with no luck.  The scanner (camera) opens but never recognizes a barcode scan successfully - or failure for that matter.  It seems nothing is happening whatsoever.  I have included straight, pertinent sample code with some options modifications for review.  I have gotten Scandit API to work and was going to try Manateeworks but both are really costly and not an option.  I am developing on Surface Pro 3 (Win 10) and that build will also be target machines when complete.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    UIElement customOverlayElement = null;
    MobileBarcodeScanner scanner;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //Create a new instance of our scanner
        scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.Dispatcher);
        scanner.Dispatcher = this.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void buttonScanDefault_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Tell our scanner to use the default overlay
        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
        //We can customize the top and bottom text of our default overlay
        scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode";
        scanner.BottomText = "Camera will automatically scan barcode\r\n\r\nPress the 'Back' button to Cancel";

        // GWS Set Options
        var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
        options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {
            ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_39, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
        };
        options.AutoRotate = false;
        options.TryHarder = false;
        options.TryInverted = false;

        //Start scanning
        scanner.Scan(options).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Result != null)
                HandleScanResult(t.Result);
        });
    }
    private void buttonScanContinuously_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Tell our scanner to use the default overlay
        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
        //We can customize the top and bottom text of our default overlay
        scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode";
        scanner.BottomText = "Camera will automatically scan barcode\r\n\r\nPress the 'Back' button to Cancel";

        // GWS Set Options
        var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
        options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {
            ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_39, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
        };
        options.AutoRotate = false;
        options.TryHarder = false;
        options.TryInverted = false;

        //Start scanning
        scanner.ScanContinuously(options, async (result) =>
        {
            var msg = "Found Barcode: " + result.Text;

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                await MessageBox(msg);
            });
        });
    }
    async void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        string msg = "";

        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
            msg = "Found Barcode: " + result.Text;
        else
            msg = "Scanning Canceled!";

        await MessageBox(msg);

    }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried by changing try harder to true?

Answer (score 0):

Simon,

I have the exact same problem. I tested your code with the latest nuget 2.1.47, the problem still exists.

You need to download the latest from [Github](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) and add the following projects (or DLLs) to your project:

```
ZXing.Net (project: zxing.portable.csproj)
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core
ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal
```

I have tested your code and it works fine. I hope this help.

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem in the hardware you are testing with. Surface Pro 3 (Win 10) [does not have an auto focus camera](http://www.lovemysurface.net/surface-pro-3-camera-quality/). I've never succeed to scan with ZXing using my Surface Pro 3, while the same application is working fine with my other windows 10 device.